# Could not find ....unspecified

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I recently wrote a java module and pushed it to maven but when I test it,there are some errors:

```
Error:Could not find PreferenceAnnotion:preference-annotation:unspecified.
Searched in the following locations:file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/PreferenceAnnotion/preference-annotation/unspecified/preference-annotation-unspecified.pom
....
Required by:
    TestPlugin:app:unspecified > com.github.merlinyu:preference-processor:1.0.0
```

My module code dependencies:

```
compile project(':preference-annotation')
```

I don't know how to fix it.

the github :https://github.com/MerlinYu/PreferenceAnnotation

Comment: If you pushed to maven, then why are you still using a local project dependency? In any case, can you show your full `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 0):

When you add Gradle dependency this way:

```
compile project(':preference-annotation')
```

Gradle searches for local Gradle module named **preference-annotation**.
It doesn't resolve the dependency through maven.

To include a dependency coming from a Maven repository you have to use this meta format (replace with proper values):

```
compile 'groupId:artifactId:version(:classifier)(@packaging)'
```

[In your case](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.merlinyu%7Cpreference-annotation%7C1.0.0%7Cjar) you have to add:

```
compile 'com.github.merlinyu:preference-annotation:1.0.0'
```